# Why is exec sp_executesql much slower than inline sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, full-text-search, sp-executesql

I have test this query in management studio and this execute very fast(less than a second)

```
declare @p_Message_0 varchar(3) = 'whh'
declare @p_CreatedTime_0 datetime = '2015-06-01'

SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT * FROM [Logs](nolock) WHERE CONTAINS([Message], @p_Message_0) AND [CreatedTime]<@p_CreatedTime_0) t
SELECT t2.* FROM (SELECT t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) as rownum FROM (SELECT * FROM [Logs](nolock) t WHERE CONTAINS([Message], @p_Message_0) AND [CreatedTime]<@p_CreatedTime_0) t) t2 WHERE rownum>0 AND rownum<=20
```

execution plan like this:
[image]

then I move it into C# ado.net, it run as this

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT * FROM [Logs](nolock) WHERE CONTAINS([Message], @p_Message_0) AND [CreatedTime]<@p_CreatedTime_0) t
SELECT t2.* FROM (SELECT t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id desc) as rownum FROM (SELECT * FROM [Logs](nolock) t WHERE CONTAINS([Message], @p_Message_0) AND [CreatedTime]<@p_CreatedTime_0) t) t2 WHERE rownum>0 AND rownum<=20',N'@p_Message_0 varchar(3),@p_CreatedTime_0 datetime',@p_Message_0='whh',@p_CreatedTime_0='2015-06-01'
```

this one run really slow(about 30s). execution plan like:[image]

I don't know what make these two plan different. Sql server is 2008 R2 with SP2, and I have tried parameter hint and OPTION (RECOMPILE), both not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating statistics. The first one uses a variable with today's date. Variables aren't sniffed so you will get a guessed distribution. The second one uses a parameter. This can be sniffed.

If the stats haven't been updated today SQL Server will think no rows exist for that date so will give a plan on that basis. Such as a nested loops plan that is estimated to execute the TVF once but actually execute it many times.

AKA [the ascending date problem](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/).

Comment: After change the datetime column index  to CLUSTERED INDEX, speed is lighting fast now , thank you very much!

Comment: btw, update statisitcs doesn't make it fast, i don't know why.

Comment: How to add OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN for linq to sql query